# Importing .txt file in R version 4.0.0 where data is enclosed in { }

Tags: r, matrix, curly-braces

I have a .txt where the data is stored in the following format:

{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {10, 9, 8, 7, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}

It is meant to be loaded as a 5x3 matrix, where the inner curly braces define the 3 vectors and the outer curly braces define the matrix.

For a single vector it was simple to use the `scan()` function to load the text as a character vector then use `substr()` to remove the braces, but it seems like there has to be a package or base function that reads vectors and matrices with this notation. I unfortunately have not been able to find anything on this topic after a few hours of searching.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not JSON? Are those inner braces curly too?

Comment: Hello, it is from a plain text (.txt) file, not JSON file... Both the inner and outer braces are curly.

Comment: JSON files are text files - just because the extension isn't JSON doesn't mean it's not a JSON file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think AllanCameron's comment is a good hint: it is close-enough to JSON that you can treat is as such (with a little bit of massaging):

```r
txt <- "{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {10, 9, 8, 7, 6}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}"
jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("\\}", "]", gsub("\\{", "[", txt)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]   10    9    8    7    6
# [3,]    1    3    5    7    9
```

To do this on a file, you must first read the entire contents in, with

```r
txt <- paste(readLines(txtfile), collapse = "\n")
```

*Edit*: code golf: `jsonlite::fromJSON(chartr("{}", "[]", txt))`.

Comment: This is certainly better than parsing it from scratch. Of course, we don't know if there are other structures such as trees or key-value pairs that this won't handle, but I think this is about as good as you can do with the given example.

Comment: I'm hoping (expecting?) the OP to come back with an error due to us not knowing if that assumption holds true. Can't know the exception if we don't try :-)

Comment: Brendan, nope, it won't work like that. If you read my answer, you'll see that we have to change the contents of the file before passing to `jsonlite::fromJSON`, which cannot happen if you jump straight to `fromJSON` from a text file.

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance guys, I really appreciate it. So if I read in the file with ```readLines())``` then use ```jsonlite::fromJSON```, it does read my file, but the resulting matrix is a 3x5 rather than a 5x3... it is simple enough to use ```t()``` to correct the issue, however.

Comment: Oddly, while `jsonlite::toJSON` provides the option to do `matrix="columnmajor"`, `readJSON` does not (inconsistent API). Your `t()` solution is by far the best.